# Показывать текущий блок и скрывать другие

Tags: html, css, jquery

Есть небольшая менюшка. Необходимо по клику показывать текущий уровень вложенности, а все остальные скрывать. Например: нажали на пункт 1 скрылись пункт 2 и 3, показались пункты 1.1, 1.2, 1.3. Кликнули на пункт 1.1 скрылись пункты 1.2, 1.3 и показалось содержимое пункта 1.1
У меня проблема заключается в том, что кликнув, например, на пункт 1 у меня скрываются пункты, 2,3,но если я нажимаю на пункт 1.1, то пункты 1.3 и 1.2
всё равно показываются. Хотя должны быть закрыты.

```js
$('.catalog-menu-item').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).children('.catalog-menu-submenu').length) {
   console.log($(this).prev());
   $(this).closest('.catalog-menu').find('.catalog-menu-item').addClass('notactive');
   $(this).removeClass('notactive').addClass('active');
   childrenParent = $(this).children('.catalog-menu-submenu')
   childrenParent.addClass('active');
   $.each(childrenParent, function(){
    if ($(this).find('li').hasClass('notactive'))
     $(this).find('li').removeClass('notactive');
   })
  }
 })
```

```css
.catalog-menu {
  background-color: #000;
}
.catalog-menu-item {
    display: block;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 40px;
    min-height: 40px;
}

.catalog-menu-submenu .catalog-menu-item {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.catalog-menu a.catalog-menu-item-link {
 display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 12px;
    width: 100%;
}

.catalog-menu-item-link:hover {
    background-color: #00a300;
}

.catalog-menu-item-link:hover:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 13px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 19px;
    background: url(img/arrow.png?v=1) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

.catalog-menu-submenu {
 /*visibility:hidden;
    opacity: 0;*/
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: default;
    background: #11385f;
    z-index: 99;
}

.catalog-menu-submenu.active,
.catalog-menu-item.active {
    display: flex!important;
}

.catalog-menu-item.notactive {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="catalog-menu">
  <li class="catalog-menu-item">
    <a class="catalog-menu-item-link">1</a>
    <ul class='catalog-menu-submenu'>
      <li class="catalog-menu-item">
        <a class="catalog-menu-item-link">1.1</a>
        <ul class='catalog-menu-submenu'>
          <li class="catalog-menu-item">text 2</li>
          <li class="catalog-menu-item">text 3</li>
          <li class="catalog-menu-item">text 4</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="catalog-menu-item">1.2</li>
      <li class="catalog-menu-item">1.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="catalog-menu-item">
     <a class="catalog-menu-item-link">2</a>
     <ul class='catalog-menu-submenu'>
       <li class="catalog-menu-item">Test 1</li>
       <li class="catalog-menu-item">Test 2</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="catalog-menu-item"> <a class="catalog-menu-item-link">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Есть же атрибут hidden. Не катит?

Comment: Михаил Алексеевич не совсем понимаю при чём тут hidden, ведь скрываться элементы должны по клику.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы все сильно усложняете. Ведь можно сделать все гораздо проще.

JQuery & CSS:

```js
$('.catalog-menu-item-link').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('current');
    $(this).closest('ul').toggleClass('show-one');

  })
```

```css
  ul.show-one > li{
    display: none;
  }
  ul.show-one > li.current,
  li.current>ul{
    display: flex;
  }
```

Не уверен, нужен ли вам toggleClass, но решил, что было бы логично таким образом возвращаться на предыдущий уровень.